# Waiting for site to load ~15seconds https issue

Tags: wordpress, ssl, woocommerce

I bought this theme[bridge wordpress] and we already implemented it on our server, however the timing responses are way too high, and we have already tweaked as much as we can.

Tweaks made: Cache cleaner plugin, Smush the images, gzip compression, changed the ssl certificate , memory alocated from 96MB to almost 1024MB, changed the server to a VPS

When running in gtmetrix and http://www.bytecheck.com/, we understand that the site takes a lot of time to initial receive the first byte , almost 15seconds, even putting the default theme it keeps doing like that.

I contacted the provider of server, the certificate provider, the theme developer i asked on wordpress forum, and nothing, the store have some tweak issues, but this kinda wait its not related, for my analysis is the ssl, that somehow is not connecting as it should, however the ssl company says it's all ok.

I wanna know if anybody can help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try figuring out what your server is doing all those 15s. To monitor wordpress, use a plugin like "query monitor" or similar.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/13xdwl0qze69pcc/Captura%20de%20tela%202015-01-30%2017.52.30.png

This is my timmings, and it's only on first byte